# CentOs 7 - how run this command (including quotes/options) using watch? (watch -n2 "command")

Tags: linux

I need run the command

```
awk '{print int($1/3600)":"int(($1%3600)/60)":"int($1%60)}' /proc/uptime
```

each 2 or 3 seconds, I try multiple options:

```
watch -n2 "'{print int($1/3600)":"int(($1%3600)/60)":"int($1%60)}' /proc/uptime"
watch -n2 "'{print int($1/3600)":"int(($1%3600)/60)":"int(\$1%60)}' /proc/uptime"
watch -n2 "'{print int(\$1/3600)":"int((\$1%3600)/60)":"int(\$1%60)}' /proc/uptime"
watch -n2 "'{print int(\$1/3600)":"int(\$1%3600/60)":"int(\$1%60)}' /proc/uptime"
watch -n2 "awk '{print int(\$1/3600)":"int(\$1%3600/60)":"int(\$1%60)}' /proc/uptime"
watch -n2 "awk '{print int($1/3600)":"int(($1%3600)/60)":"int($1%60)}' /proc/uptime"
watch -n2 "awk '{print int(\$1/3600)":"int((\$1%3600)/60)":"int(\$1%60)}' /proc/uptime"
```

and more...

but never work for me

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have to escape `"` inside `"` too.

```
watch "awk '{print int(\$1/3600)\":\"int(\$1%3600/60)\":\"int(\$1%60)}' /proc/uptime"
```

but really, just

```
watch -x awk '{print int($1/3600)":"int($1%3600/60)":"int($1%60)}' /proc/uptime
```

When in doubt, use `printf "%q"` to quote stuff. I wonder if the following is fine:

```
watch "$(printf "%q " awk '{print int($1/3600)":"int(($1%3600)/60)":"int($1%60)}' /proc/uptime)"
```

But in interactive shell, I would just make a function, it's the simplest:

```
f() { awk '{print int($1/3600)":"int(($1%3600)/60)":"int($1%60)}' /proc/uptime; }
export -f f
watch bash -c f
```

Comment: thanks @KamilCuk, how we can ADD seconds/time to command?, for example run each 2 or 5 seconds ?

Comment: again this: `watch -n2 awk '{print int($1/3600)":"int($1%3600/60)":"int($1%60)}' /proc/uptime` return error

Comment: `watch -n2 "awk '{print int(\$1/3600)\":\"int(\$1%3600/60)\":\"int(\$1%60)}' /proc/uptime"`. ?? You just add `-n2` as is, without modyfing anything else...